# Django model inheritance: ForeignKey on parent, no related_name access to child model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-inheritance

Example situation as follows:

```
# models.py
class Form(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class A(models.Model):
    form = models.ForeignKey(Form)

class B(A):
    name = models.CharField()

# view.py
form = Form.objects.get(id=1)
form.a_set.all()  # works
form.b_set.all()  # doesn't work
```

I would like to access all the related `B` Objects via the parent class `A` foreign key but I can't seem to do this. And if I access them via `A` then I just get the generic parent class query set. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you inherit from a concrete model, there will be two tables (unlike inheriting from an abstract model) for `Parent` and `Child` models.

Django will implicitly create a `OneToOneField` from `Child` to `Parent` model named [`parent_ptr`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#specifying-the-parent-link-field), thus:

```
B.objects.filter(a_ptr__form=form)
# B.objects.filter(a_ptr__form_id=1)
```

will give you the desired `QuerySet`.